# Is it possible to run two different Rails apps on the same domain (using a subdirectory)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, nginx

I have a game that I developed in Rails 3.1 that I would like to add to my existing Rails 2.3.8 without having to upgrade it.  Is it possible to have this 3.1 game app exist on the same domain, something like http://mydomain.com/game?  So any url with /game would direct to the Rails 3.1 app and all other urls would direct to the regular 2.3 app?  How would I approach this using nginx using a subdirectory (I'd rather not use a subdomain and lose seo)?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this but its easier to use a subdomain like game.mydomain.com because then you can deal with this problem using nginx. For the seperation of the different ruby and rails versions use rvm (https://rvm.io/).

Then you can create a nginx config like this:

```
upstream mydomain.com {
        server unix:/var/run/thin/mydomain.0.sock;
        server unix:/var/run/thin/mydomain.1.sock;
        server unix:/var/run/thin/mydomain.2.sock;
        server unix:/var/run/thin/mydomain.3.sock;
}
upstream game.mydomain.com {
        server unix:/var/run/thin/game.mydomain.0.sock;
        server unix:/var/run/thin/game.mydomain.1.sock;
        server unix:/var/run/thin/game.mydomain.2.sock;
        server unix:/var/run/thin/game.mydomain.3.sock;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mydomain.com;
        access_log /path/to/rails/app/log/access.log;
        error_log /path/to/rails/app/log/error.log;
        root /path/to/rails/app/public;
        index index.html;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;

                if (-f $request_filename/index.html) {
                        rewrite (.*) $1/index.html break;
                }

                if (-f $request_filename.html) {
                        rewrite (.*) $1.html break;
                }

                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                        proxy_pass http://mydomain.com;
                        break;
                }
        }
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name game.mydomain.com;
        access_log /path/to/rails/app/log/access.log;
        error_log /path/to/rails/app/log/error.log;
        root /path/to/rails/app/public;
        index index.html;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;

                if (-f $request_filename/index.html) {
                        rewrite (.*) $1/index.html break;
                }

                if (-f $request_filename.html) {
                        rewrite (.*) $1.html break;
                }

                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                        proxy_pass http://game.mydomain.com;
                        break;
                }
        }
}
```

That should do it for you if its acceptable to use subdomains instead of subfolders.

If you really wanna use subdirectories you can do this using nginx `location`directive:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location

Comment: Also its important to keep the config in one file,... because otherwise the naming of the config files would be important.

Comment: Thanks for your answer davidb, but i'd really rather not use a subdomain for seo purposes...

Comment: Subdomains arent a generell downside: http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/subdomains-and-subdirectories/

Comment: But you lose all the seo for that subdomain.

Comment: What excectly do you mean when you say "seo"? The page rank?

Comment: Sorry, yea, the page rank derived from search engine optimization.  I was under the impression that sub domains do not transfer on 'link juice.'

Comment: I know but there are pretty much wannabe seos out there therefore I asked,... Yes of cause google treats it as sth. completely different but it is. You wrote two apps for it so it doesnt seem to be one. Whatever,... have a look at post edit...

Answer (score 0):

Yes

Run it on a Sub Domain you dont want to cause problems with your existing Application.

Comment: What about doing it with a subdirectory?  I'd rather not lose SEO.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but it will not effect your SEO.
You want to know the most important thing about SEO it is very simple.
Content is king, the more content the better. but you can run it on a sub directory also it is up to you.